# Getting All Values from Comma Separated String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 1 String Variable in JavaScript which contains 3 Comma separated values shown below:

```
var session = "mick@yahoo.com,123456,f_id=8";
```

I want to get all above 3 comma separated values in 3 different variables. What I have achieved so far is getting last comma separated value in elem2 variable and getting other 2 comma separated values 1st and 2nd one in elem1 variable.

```
var elem1 = session.split(",");

var elem2 = elem1.pop();

document.write("elem1 = "+elem1+"<br/>elem2 = "+elem2);
```

So my program is not working fine as I wants, please I need quick working solution so that I have another variable elem3 and I will get following output in my browser:

```
elem1 = mick@yahoo.com
elem2 = 123456
elem3 = f_id=8
```

Comment: you can wait ES6 and can do [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this: `var [email, number, id] = session.split(",")`

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following:

```
// Initially, we split are comma separated string value on commas.
// In the values an array of these values is stored.
var values = session.split(",");
// Then we get each value based on it's position in the array.
var email = values[0];
var number = values[1];
var id = values[2];
```

As a side note, I would suggest you use meaningful names for your variables like above. The names `elem1`, `elem2` and `elem3` are a bit vague and in future thses namings may obscure even you, let alone another reader of your code.

Comment: Just curious to ask can we make this program generic, I mean for any number of variables it works ??

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes you can. But pay attention on the position of each value in the string. For instance, if the `number` is first and `email` is second,  `"123456,mick@yahoo.com,f_id=8";` then you would assign to the wrong variable the wrong value. However, if the arrangement of the variables doesn't matter, you will not have to address any issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the session data in a [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Below iterates through each split string and adds it to an Object.

```
var myData = {};

// ...

for(var i = 0, x = session.split(","); i < x.length; i++) {
    switch(i) {
        case 0: myData.email = x[i]; break;
        case 1: myData.number = x[i]; break;
        case 2: myData.f_id = x[i]; break;
    }
}
```

If you're dealing with multiple data values, it's best to make an array of objects, like so.

```
var myData = [];

// ...

myData.push({
    email: x[0],
    number: x[1],
    f_id: x[2]
});
```

And so on. This is a form of [JSON Notation](http://www.json.org/). The output would look like this:

```
[
    {
        email: "mick@yahoo.com",
        number: "123456",
        f_id: "f_id=8"
    },
    {
        // Another session, etc.
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use string.replace with a callback as parameter. Very flexible!

Check this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

For your usecase you may end up with:

```
function writeParts(match, email, number, id, offset, string) {
    document.write("email = "+email+"<br/>number = "+number);
}
// match not-comma followed by a comma (three times)
session.replace(/([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)/, writeParts);
```